# Woocommerce taxes not working after update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a big problem with my Woocommerce shop. After upgrading to version 3.6.4 (latest) and WP 5.2.1 suddenly my Woocommerce admin.php page stops loading. Additionally, it seems that taxes are not added to my products and therefore not added in the checkout.

In other words, when opening the taxes page, half the page is loaded but the table with tax info always says "loading".

Looking at the console I see these errors:

```
TypeError: a.ui is undefined draggable.min.js:11:133
TypeError: a.ui is undefined slider.min.js:11:126
TypeError: a.widget is not a function iris.min.js:4:16724
TypeError: a.widget is not a function menu.min.js:11:138
TypeError: a.widget is not a function autocomplete.min.js:11:147
TypeError: s(...).iris is not a function settings.min.js:1:806
```

After Googling I found some possible solutions like enqueuing scripts in theme-functions.php. However it works for some scripts (error goes away) but not for `settings.min.js` for example.

```
function test_load_scripts($hook) {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-menu');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete');
    wp_enqueue_script('iris');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
    wp_enqueue_script('settings', 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/settings.min.js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'test_load_scripts');
```

Further I tried to enable/disable plugins. However I think it's coming from the Woocommerce plugin itself since the errors are only visible on the admin pages for Woocommerce.

Does anybody know what cause this? And better how to fix it? I'm pretty new to WP and Woo so I hope someone can help.

Comment: 3.4.6 is not the latest version… 3.6.4 is the latest... It's not possible to guess that with the provided information. This seems to be related to some WooCommerce customizations made by you, your theme or a plugin…